# В firefox не отсылается пост через js

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

В файрфоксе не работает данный скрипт, почему может это быть ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#widget_languages li a.lang_btn").click(function() {
     name = $(this).attr('datalang');
     $.post("lang", {'name': name});
     location.reload();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Покажите консоль браузера с ошибками.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, попробуйте вызывать `location.reload()` только при успешном выполнении запроса в коллбэк-функции `success`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#widget_languages li a.lang_btn").click(function() {
     name = $(this).attr('datalang');
     $.post("lang", 
            {'name': name}, 
            function( data ) {
                location.reload();
     });
  });
});
</script>
```

P.S. Раз уж Вы используете ajax, то может вообще стоит отказаться от перезагрузки страницы? А просто там же в `success`, выводить необходимую информацию на страницу с помощью javascript.

Comment: Спасибо помогло.

Answer (score 2):

После отправки AJAX-запроса вы сразу вызываете `location.reload();`. Запрос не успевает отправиться, и страница перезагружается.

Обновляйте страницу только после того, как получите ответ на запрос.